# Multilanguage website on two different domains

Tags: php, multi-language

I'm in search of the best method to keep two websites, on two different domains, sharing the same server, identical but in the same time one to be in English, and another in another language.

I was thinking on a system like this:

*Have a php file with text for "about us" stored in a variable so when it's accessed by ".com" domain to get the value in English, and when it's accessed by ".it" gets the value in Italian.*

Is this the best practice? Can you recommend me anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1.
You can use .pot file to store translation and use wordpress default translator functions for all of your strings such as __e()

Method 2:
It is better to use any translator plugin since it will do all the necessory work for you.

Few of them are here

https://wpml.org/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/